# How to add prefix to column name according to data in another column

Tags: python, dataframe, prefix, dummy-variable

There is a dataframe like bellow

```
import pandas as pd
  
data = {‘ID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
‘LABEL': [’text', ‘logo', ‘logo', ‘person’,’text’,’text’,’person’,’logo'],
        ‘cluster_label': [c_0, c_0, c_0, c_1, c_1, c_2, c_2, c_3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to make dummy columns for the “cluster_label” column

```
pd.get_dummies(df,columns=[‘cluster_label'])
```

however I need to add a prefix regraded to the LABEL column.

Basically, the columns must be  text_c_0, logo_c_0, …
How can I do that

Many thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    'LABEL': ['text', 'logo', 'logo', 'person', 'text', 'text', 'person', 'logo'],
    'cluster_label': ['c_0', 'c_0', 'c_0', 'c_1', 'c_1', 'c_2', 'c_2', 'c_3']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

pd.get_dummies(df,columns=['cluster_label'])



df['dummy'] = df.apply (lambda row: row['LABEL']+'_'+row['cluster_label'], axis=1)

pd.get_dummies(df['dummy'])

## If you want to keep ['ID','LABEL','cluster_label'] in your df :
df = df.join(pd.get_dummies(df['dummy']))
```

Comment: It helped to remove a bunch of unnecessary lines from my script.Thank you so much